# Альтернатива include

Tags: php, html

Есть вот такой кусочек кода, вроде все работает, но есть одно но, функция `file_get_contents` не хочет считывать из файла php код, считывает его как коментарий

```
$header = file_get_contents('tpl/header.php');
```

Данный код нужен для тогоm, чтобы не писать в шаблон, типа `include('tpl/header.php')`, а просто поставить

```
<?=$header?>
```

В основном для красоты!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можешь весь вывод header.php впихнуть в переменную $header, т.е.:

```
<?
    $header = "
    <header>
    ...
    </header>";
```

и потом же подключать

```
<?=$header?>
```

Comment: Тож норм вариант, но мне надо в переменную инфу не на прямую заносить, а через подключение файла. А так спасибо !!!

Answer (score 3):

Ужасно конечно подобное делать, но раз уж Вы решили поизвращаться то попробуйте:

```
ob_start();
eval(file_get_contents('tpl/header.php');
$header = ob_get_clean();
//или проще
ob_start();
include('tpl/header.php');
$header = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: А если надо нескольким переменным назначить include например

    $header = file_get_contents('tpl/header.php');
    $footer = file_get_contents('tpl/footer.php');
Извеняюсь но я не спец в PHP

Comment: stop using fucking eval, omg

Comment: @AlexWindHope абсолютно с Вами согласен, вообщем ни одну из приведенных в ответе конструкций лучше не использовать.
@Berserker повторяем тоже самое, только меняем header на footer.

Comment: А зачем что-то присваивать переменным?  Нельзя ли просто сделать инклуд нужного файла в нужном месте?

Comment: @Photon НУЖНО просто сделать инклюд. но читаем внимательно вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос я прочитал внимательно..  И после прочтения решил переспросить у автора..

Comment: Все это для красоты и удобства

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте посмотреть шаблонизатор Twig или другие, уже готовые поделки.

Comment: Спасибо! Но это лишнее. Зачем зря напрягать сайт. PHP сам по себе как шаблонизатор.

Comment: @Berserker,вы не правы. объяснять не буду, слишком много писать...

Comment: Вполне возможно что и не прав. Просто начитался про эти шаблонизаторы, по этому и не хорошо о них отзываюсь.

Comment: Гляну, может и понравится !

Comment: А лучше свой написать шаблонизатор, с минимальном функционалом. Хороший опыт...

Answer (score 1):

А если так:

```
<?=eval($header)?>
```

Уже не красиво?

Comment: На такое ругается !

Comment: А что пишет? И да, у тебя header.php может открыться без ошибок отдельно?, если да, то можно по-другому сделать без прибигания к eval

Comment: чтобы не ругался надо `echo` убрать.

      <?eval($header)?>

Comment: <?= - короткая запись echo, судя по ошибке ему не нравится то что в файле header.php на первой строке стоит <?

Comment: Ну тогда: $header = file_get_contents(УРЛ_САЙТА.'/tpl/header.php');
Т.е. указывай полный путь и тогда можно будет без eval. Например:
 $header = file_get_contents('http://mysite.ru/tpl/header.php');

Comment: Но ведь такой вариант 

     $header = file_get_contents
php код в файле не читает, а воспроизводит как комментарий.

Comment: Надо вот эту

    file_get_contents

 функцию заменить на какую то другую

Comment: Ты же сказал, что там только html. Да и в конце концов сделайте, как Вам предлагает FLK

Comment: В файле `header.php` один html, но хотелось бы поставить PHP, но нельзя. А такой метод какой предлагает FLK не хочет работать выдает ошибку.

Comment: что пишет?